# Updated Select In with 5000 rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a mysql query to UPDATE the `new_update='Y'` only for the `ABC_Code` listed in the `where` clause. The ABC_Code are almost 5000 records (select query below)

```
Select ABC_Code,new_update from mydata where ABC_Code in ('AZ-2TGG-7','AZ-1CLJ-3','10PAK:AZ-040R-6','10PAK:AZ-040S-1');
```

Is this the best way to write the Update query

```
update mydata set new_update='Y' where ABC_Code in ('AZ-2TGG-7','AZ-1CLJ-3','10PAK:AZ-040R-6','10PAK:AZ-040S-1');
```

Comment: what's wrong with the second query? it seems to be fine, didn't it work for you?

Comment: How do you obtain  The value in IN clause  ... are in someway  a result from a query?